# Find the minimum value of $\frac {\sin \alpha \sin \beta}{\sin^2 \frac {\gamma}{2}}+...$

Tags: trigonometry

Find the minimum value of the following expression 
$$ \frac {\sin \alpha \sin \beta}{\sin^2 \frac {\gamma}{2}}+ \frac {\sin \beta \sin \gamma}{\sin^2 \frac {\alpha}{2}}+ \frac {\sin \gamma \sin \alpha}{\sin^2 \frac {\beta}{2}},$$
where $\alpha, \beta$ and $\gamma -$ angles of some triangle?

Comment: Usually, such symmetrical expressions achieve their extreme values when all variables are equal.

Comment: The answer is clear. Of interest is the proof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: use $$\gamma=\pi-\alpha-\beta$$ or $$\alpha+\beta+\gamma=\pi$$ and the Lagrange Multiplier Method
now i have another idea:
with $$2A=bc\sin(\alpha),2A=ac\sin(\beta),\sin(\gamma/2)=\sqrt{\frac{(s-a)(s-b)}{ab}}$$ we get for the first summand (after some Algebra)
$$\frac{4A^2}{(s-a)(s-b)c^2}$$ etc and our sum is given by
$$4s(\frac{s-a}{a^2}+\frac{s-b}{b^2}+\frac{s-c}{c^2})$$